# More descriptive, strong verb to replace "came back"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am writing an exposé in writing class. In my lead I am trying to find a verb to replace "came back"
Here is the example:

> Billy Bob "came back" from behind to win the trophy.

In the active voice verb tense, what would the best verb to replace this?

Comment: You could replace the whole verb phrase "came back from behind" with "made a comeback"; the understanding that it's a comeback "from behind" is implicit and doesn't need to be stated, as there is no concept of a comeback from in front.

Comment: Comeback is a VERY common way to phrase this in spoken English in America by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Doing a google search of [comeback](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=define:+comeback) lists a bunch of synonyms:

> synonyms: resurgence, recovery, return, rally, upturn

You can then get synonyms of those words. Going down the synonym rabbit hole, you get a ton of options:

> resurrection, reappearance, reemergence, regeneration, resumption, recommencement, continuation, renaissance, convalescence, regroup, reassemble, re-form, reunite, rally

Billy Bob **rallied** from behind to win the trophy.

Comment: "Rally" is good, but "rally from behind" is redundant. One cannot rally from any other position. @John Clifford makes this point above as well

Answer (score 0):

Consider this expression often used in sports commentary:

> Billy Bob **produces a stirring fight-back** to win the
>   trophy.